# Distance between parallel lines inside of a rectangle

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have 2 parallel lines which are touching a rectangle.
I know the coordinates `(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)`

How can I find with Mathematica from that the orthogonal distance between the lines?

[image]

Comment: Can you post you real coordinate?

Comment: `RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}], {x3, y4}]`

Comment: `x1 = 0.;
y1 = 532.964;
x2 = 950;
y2 = 545.204;

x3 = 0.;
y3 = 235.665;
x4 = 950;
y4 = 247.905;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @yode points out MMA has clever built in functions like `RegionDistance` to help with problems like this.

However, in case speed is a requirement (if you had many such calculations to perform), you would certainly be better off in this instance implementing a mathematical solution:

```
ParallelLineDistance[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}] := 
 Module[{w, v},
  w = {x3, y3} - {x1, y1};
  v = {x2, y2} - {x1, y1};
  Norm[w - v.w/Norm[v]^2 v]
 ]
```

Timings:

```
RepeatedTiming[
  ParallelLineDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}]
 ]
```

> {0.00001189, 297.274}

```
RepeatedTiming[
  RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}], {x3, y3}]
 ]
```

> {0.00025, 297.274}

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is your solution so much faster than `RegionDistance`?

Comment: In short because `RegionDistance` can handle many other much broader cases, and therefore likely has to do a lot of checking / pre-parsing of the problem - you'd have to ask others on the site here for the details if you're interested. Whereas simple algebra is about as quick as it gets. Note that if speed really is an issue then there may be faster ways still, especially in the context of evaluating `ParallelLineDistance` over a list.

Comment: By the way, `Projection[]` is built-in...

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{mp = {x1, 1 + y1}/2, cp, ri},
  cp = Cross[mp - {0, y1}];
  ri = RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[{mp, mp + cp}], 
    InfiniteLine[{{x3, 0}, {x3 + (1/(1 - y1)) x1, 1}}]]; 
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], 
    Rectangle[], 
    Point[{{0, y1}, {x1, 1}, {x3, 0}, {x3 + (1/(1 - y1)) x1, 1}}], 
    Green, Line[{{0, y1}, {x1, 1}}], Red, 
    Line[{{x3, 0}, {x3 + (1/(1 - y1)) x1, 1}}], Blue, 
    Line[{mp, ri[[1]]}], 
    Text[Framed[Norm[mp - ri[[1]]], 
      Background -> White], (mp + ri[[1]])/2]}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]],
 {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variation of the answer by [Quantum_Oli](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128949/37895)

Your data:

```
x1=0.;y1=532.964;x2=950;y2=545.204;x3=0.;y3=235.665;x4=950;y4=247.905;
```

$\{\text{$\Delta $x},\text{$\Delta $y}\}$ from `Point3` to the `Point1`

```
p3=Flatten@Differences[{{x3,y3},{x1,y1}}]
```

> {0.,297.299}

$\{\text{$\Delta $x},\text{$\Delta $y}\}$ from `Point2` to the `Point1`

```
p2=Flatten@Differences[{{x2,y2},{x1,y1}}]
```

> {-950.,-12.24}

Distance between the lines

```
DistanceBetweenLines[w_,v_]:=Norm[w-v.w/Norm[v]^2 v]
DistanceBetweenLines[p3,p2]
```

> 297.274